# function in smarty php where to set?

Tags: php, cakephp, smarty

My goal is to output the content of a h2-tag (if existing) or instead the title of the page (if not existing) of a copy-text.

I have a smarty template file where I need to include this.
Inside of the classes I can't define it. If I try the website shows a blank page... so how or where can I define this?

I came up with this code which needs to be included the template file:

```
$newtitle=$this->websites->description
preg_match( '#<h2[^>]*>(.*?)</h2>#i', $newtitle, $match );
if (isset($match[1])) {
    $newtitle = (($match[1]).' '.$this->websites->getYear());
else {
    $newtitle = ('NOT FOUND - '.$this->getWebTitle());
}
```

I am not familiar with PHP work set. I just would like to implement this easily.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a `}` bracket in front of `else {`

This will result in a PHP error, which might be causing the blank page.

If this is not the issue, try looking in the servers error_log file. It will show you an error message which should help you debug the issue.